# Beautiful Soup unable to find selectors which have id and class in them

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a selector in an html page. Most of my selectors are returning the correct result except the ones that have an id and class in them both.

Example:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
selectors_giving_incorrect_value = ["input#symbol input.btn-primary",
                                    "input.stackbar input#symbol.stackbar",
                                    "div div#logo.stackarea"]

selectors_working_right = ["div", "div p"]

for i in selectors_giving_incorrect_value:
    soup.select(i))
```

The output is always blank:

```
[]
[]
[]
```

Wanted to check if there is a special way to check for these kind of selectors which have both id and class in them?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"myClass","id":"myID"})
```

I would also assume `soup.select("div#IDname.ClassName")` works if using a selector, can't really test right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct this selector:

`"input#symbol input.btn-primary"`

It should be:

`"input.btn-primary input#symbol"`

I know it violates original css selector rules, but it seems to work. When you reorder id and class - this selector will not work. Probably it depends of which parser you use.

Comment: input#symbol input.btn-primary specifies that there is a tag input with id = symbol & it has a children tag input with class = btn primary. Wouldn't reversing the order find different selectors?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in a practice I've got another behavior. In my case, bs4 founds tags which have specified id and class simultaneously. Did you try it on your data?